# Stop music from another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I have an app with music , you can play music in 2 methods -> click on cell and another view controller is opening or click on a button and the music is playing .

How can i do that only one sound to be playing ?

I was trying this :
`[musicViewContreoller.player stop]`. I synthesize player. but is not working . any ideea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by making the player a propetry in AppDelegate and then i use this :

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.player stop];
```

Answer (score 1):

u can crate singleton audio class with init method and methods for stop\play\pause etc.

can look this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877110/objective-c-need-help-creating-an-avaudioplayer-singleton) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600560/audio-with-singleton-class)

hope this help

Comment: only music controller.
 or u can just only create audio singleton model and change all actions for calling music in music controller and music list controller.